# Excel Find and replace using variables

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'd like to know if there's a way to FIND AND REPLACE in this way :

I need to find all cells that contains `apt` followed by a number. But the number is always different. So is there a script or something that would do that?

FIND : `apt XX` `(the 2 Xs representing the numbers)`

REPLACE BY : `app 30`

So it would locate all the places where `apt + a number`

Because I have thousands of lines, and I don't want to do :

FIND : apt 01...

FIND : apt 02...

FIND : apt 03...

and so on

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for:

```
Sub findApt()
    Dim count As Integer
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While i <= count
        If (InStr(Range("B" & i), "apt")) Then
            Range("B" & i) = Mid(Range("B" & i), 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("apt", Range("B" & i)) - 1) & "app 30"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

This assumes that your data is in column B.  Enjoy!

Comment: Working but I need to replace the 3 numbers following that word too. Because sometimes I have "apt 01"..."apt 201"..."apt 24"...and I need to replace all this

Comment: Yes, it will replace it as you described.  What you do is you enable the Developer tab in the top bar (by going to Excel Options), then click Visual Basic.  In there, you click on Sheet1 (or whatever sheet your data is on) then just paste this code.  To actually run it, go back to the spreadsheet, click Macros (in the Developer tab), and select Sheet1.findApt and hit Run.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried but it only change "apt" to "app"...but the numbers stay there.

Comment: I was under the impression that that was what you were looking for?

Comment: Or does every instance of "apt" + (a number) need to be changed to "app 30"?

Comment: What does your data look like?  Is every entry "apt" + (a number), or is there a mix?

Comment: It looks like this (I made an example) : http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/8890797/640/8890797.png

Comment: As you can see, some "ADD" (address) do have "apt"+(a number), and some don't. But I need to replace them all. All the "apt"+(a number) in the B column

Comment: And will "apt" + (a number) always be at the end of the cell?

Comment: And is it fair to say that if the cell contains "apt" then it needs to be replaced?

Comment: Well if the cell contains "apt", there's always a maximum 3 characters number next to it. So it needs to scan the column B and if it detects a "apt"+(a number), it needs to be replaced by "app 30".

Comment: And will "apt" + (a number) always be at the end?

Comment: Yes it will always be at the end of the cell

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Really apprecited! My production flow will be alot faster now thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx are indeed useful, but I believe for this the built-in 'regex' is good enough. From the help file:

> Use the asterisk to find any string of characters. For example, s*d finds "sad" and "started".
>
> Use the question mark to find any single character. For example, s?t finds "sat" and "set".

So in your case just press Ctrl+H to get Search And Replace dialogue, then write `apt *` into search box and `app 30` into replace box.

PS: It is not clear from your question whether there are some cells that contain `apt` followed by something else than a number and that should be preserved. If this is the case, go with RegEx, either as Emmanuel suggests or by using `Scripting.Regex` in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install Find And Replace [Excel Regex](http://www.codedawn.com/regex-find-replace-download.php). Allows you to use regular expression to find and replace.

Comment: Looks useful but I'm on a Mac :S